# Porque o atributo draggable com o valor false não está funcionando?

Tags: html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p draggable="true">Esse parágrafo é arrastável.</p>
    <p draggable="false">Esse parágrafo não é arrastável.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

O atributo `draggable` é usado para poder definir se um determinado elemento é arrastável ou não. Por padrão imagens e links são arrastáveis, mas no caso do exemplo acima os parágrafos são arrastável mesmo se o atributo `draggable` estiver omitido e no caso do segundo parágrafo mesmo dando um `draggable="false"` o parágrafo continua sendo arrastádo, por que isso acontece? não era para o parágrafo não ser arrastádo?

Comment: Mas ele está draggble

Comment: Onde você esta rodando isso?

Comment: @Diego Filipe Pedro Santos, No chrome!

Comment: O último está desativado, mas não desativa!

Comment: É exatamente este código que você ta tentando rodar por que nem no jsfiddle roda

Comment: @hugocsl, o atributo `draggable` é um atributo enumerado se o valor tiver como `true` o elemento é arrastável e se tiver `false` o elemento não é arrastável, mas mesmo dando `false` o elemento continua sendo arrastável.

Comment: @Diego Filipe Pedro Santos, ai o parágrafo não está sendo arrastado?

Comment: Não, olha aí https://jsfiddle.net/zb910pqu/7/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101293/discussion-between-diego-filipe-pedro-santos-and-ledeveloper).

Comment: No snippet acima o parágrafo não está sendo arrastável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te falei já está funcionando, acredito que vc tenha entendido o `draggable` do `HTML` de maneira equivocada, achando que ele funcionaria como o `draggable` do `jQuery`, só que não.

Repare nessa imagem um exemplo simples, e veja como com `draggable="true/false"` é possível sim determinar quais elementos podem ou não ser arrastados. E veja tb pq é interessante que alguns deles realmente sejam `draggables`, principalmente para quem tem um dispositivo sem `teclado` e só tem o `mouse` como recurso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<p draggable="true">Esse parágrafo é arrastável.</p>
<p draggable="false">Esse parágrafo não é arrastável.</p>

<img draggable="true" src="https://www.placecage.com/100/100">
<img draggable="false" src="https://www.placecage.com/100/100">

<a draggable="true" href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
<a draggable="false" href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
```

Comment: mas quando é selecionado o texto ele continua sendo arrastável o que fazer ?

Comment: @ledeveloper não sei mano... Se vc deu o atributo arrastavel para um elemento que nativamente não deveria ter, ai vc que decide. O que eu vejo, eh que não faz sentido vc ter um texto que seja arrastavel, já um link eh interessante. Essa eh a flexibilidade do html, vc pode dar uma característica que não eh nativa a um elemento, mas se eh correto ou não, ou se faz sentido ou não eh por sua conta

Comment: vlw man, pela atenção!

Comment: @ledeveloper talvez não fosse exatamente o que vc esperava do atributo, mas sendo nativo do html não seria nada muito "sofisticado"